# (php) create link based on form input and pass it to iframe source

Tags: php, forms

after a wordpress update to 5.5 my form stopped working. Its purpose is to collect input and pass it to iframe src on another page. I have some code in php implemented through shortcode to my wordpress page. Does anyone have any idea why it does not work? It did work perfectly before the update.

Form code alon with php:

```
<?php    
function addlink($go) {
    if ($go <> "") $link = $go; else $link ="index";
    return $link;
    }       
?>          
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['fh'])) $fhList = $_POST['fhList'];
    if(isset($_POST['from'])) $from = $_POST['from']; else $from='';
    if(isset($_POST['to'])) $to = $_POST['to']; else $to='';
    if(isset($_POST['adults_number'])) $adults_number = $_POST['adults_number']; else $adults_number='';
    if(isset($_POST['style'])) $style = $_POST['style'];
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Sprawdź") {
        
        $link = 'https://roomadmin.pl/####';
        $link .= '?fhList=' . $fhList;
        $link .= '&style=' . $style;
        $link .= '&arrival=' . $from;
        $link .= '&departure=' . $to;
        $link .= '&rooms[0][numberOfGuests]=' . $adults_number;
  }
    ?>    
<div class="fixedbar">
<div class="boxfloat">
<ul id="tips">
<li>       
    <div id="reservation"> 
          <form id='reservation-form' action='https://marea.ustka.pl/####' method='post'>
              <input name="fhList" value="51e0ee9985761d73e8e68252223d358644d5121d,bca1d3edd0c0c97c4408e77d1763478db138c8f2" type="hidden">
              <input name="style" value="{%22color_accent%22%3A%22%2350A4AF%22}" type="hidden">
              <input id="from" name="from" type="date" placeholder="Przyjazd" value ="<?php echo $from; ?>">
              <input id="to" name="to" type="date" placeholder="Wyjazd" value ="<?php echo $to; ?>">
              <select name="adults_number" placeholder="LICZBA OSÓB">
                  <option value="">LICZBA OSÓB</option>
                  <option value="1" <?php if($adults_number==1) echo 'selected'; ?> >1 osoba</option>
                  <option value="2" <?php if($adults_number==2) echo 'selected'; ?> >2 osoby</option>
                  <option value="3" <?php if($adults_number==3) echo 'selected'; ?> >3 osoby</option>
                  <option value="4" <?php if($adults_number==4) echo 'selected'; ?> >4 osoby</option>
              </select>
              <input value="SPRAWDŹ DOSTĘPNOŚĆ" style="padding=8px;" type="submit" name="submit">
          </form>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>    
</div>
</div>
```

And code on the page where the iframe should get the data:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['fh'])) $fhList = $_POST['fhList'];
    if(isset($_POST['from'])) $from = $_POST['from']; else $from='';
    if(isset($_POST['to'])) $to = $_POST['to']; else $to='';
    if(isset($_POST['adults_number'])) $adults_number = $_POST['adults_number']; else $adults_number='';
    if(isset($_POST['style'])) $style = $_POST['style'];

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Sprawdź") {
        $link = 'https://roomadmin.pl/####';
        $link .= '?fhList=' . $fhList;
        $link .= '&style=' . $style;
        $link .= '&arrival=' . $from;
        $link .= '&departure=' . $to;
        $link .= '&rooms[0][numberOfGuests]=' . $adults_number;
  }
?>
<iframe id="ra-reservation-iframe" scrolling="no"  style="width:100%;border: none;margin:0;padding:0;min-height:600px;" src="<?php echo $link; ?>"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is html form issue, php handling looks good

this below is a submitter of your form it creates message: `submit=SPRAWDŹ DOSTĘPNOŚĆ`

```
<input value="SPRAWDŹ DOSTĘPNOŚĆ" style="padding: 8px;" type="submit" name="submit">
```

and here is validation - "if there is a message `submit=Sprawdź` then OK", but your form sends different message...

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Sprawdź") { ...
```

To fix this you need make them identical, like this:

```
<input value="sprawdź dostępność" style="padding=8px;" type="submit" name="submit">
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="sprawdź dostępność") { ...
```

It should fix the problem. You should also correct last line - like this (spaces are important)

```
<iframe id="ra-reservation-iframe" scrolling="no"  style="width: 100%; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height: 600px;" src="<?php echo $link; ?>"></iframe>
```

By the way, don't publish internal addresses - someone may use it to hurt you. You aren't IT specialist, so can be an easy target.

```
https://roomadmin.pl/#####
https://marea.ustka.pl/#####
```